Fetch gzipped json using just fetch json.gz
fetch('./data.json.gz',{"Content-Encoding": "gzip" , "Content-Type": "application/json"})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

result:
SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern.

data.json:
{
  "data":1
}

and it was gzipped with gzip data.json
According to answer here this should work?
How to fetch json.gz in a modern browser without third-party libraries?
Is this possible - are my headers insufficient?


Headers go in a headers property of the second object you passed. The way you did this will not work.  2. compression via Content-Encoding is transparently handled by the browser and your server. You shouldn't have to think about it on the browser side. If the server didn't do what you expect, that's a server-side issue.


The code you showed is a request being made by a client.
The headers Content-Type and Content-Encoding are used when sending data — for example, if your client were to POST some JSON to the server.
The corresponding headers that the client should use when requesting data (e.g. GET) are named Accept and Accept-Encoding.
And — as pointed out in a comment on your question — the headers belong on the headers property of the RequestInit object, which is the second parameter used by the global fetch function.
Here's how you can refactor the example code you showed (assuming that the server is operating correctly):
async function example() {
  try {
    const requestInit = {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
      },
    };
    const response = await fetch("./data.json.gz", requestInit);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (cause) {
    console.error(cause);
  }
}

example();

Code in the TypeScript Playground

Modern browsers automatically decompress gzip-compressed response bodies when using the fetch API. See these SO questions for more info:

Is GZIP Automatically Decompressed by Browser?
Fetch raw gzip-encoded web page into Uint8Array


Thanks. fetch("./data.json.gz") is not the right way to do it - as you said, gzipping is automatic between the browser and server. My misunderstanding here is that fetch('file.json') requires a server... unlike just opening index.html.
So I solved this by fixing my nginx config file, and loading file.json not file.json.gz
